# convert date format in php like 6th of November 2017 to 2017-11-6

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

i want to convert a date format to another using php 
**6th of November 2017** to **2017-11-6**

i tried

```
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('6th of November 2017'));
```

but it always returns `01-01-1970`

Answer (score 4):

When you create date from specific format then use `createFromFormat` of date.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('jS \o\f F Y', '6th of November 2017');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Note: If you have string in your format then you have to escape that string (with `\`) for conversation

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/Q9ONW)

Comment: date("Y-m-d", strtotime("6th November 2017"))  this is not working thats why i am asking

Comment: @B.Desai  correct. I forgot that. already up-voted for your post

Comment: Your code is great ! but i come to one more problem when the date decreases or increases it changes like   1st 2nd 3rd then 4th after th is working but what when it is 1st 2nd or third ??
i did  like this when creating the date
$data[] = $date->format("jS \of F Y");

Comment: Try updated code @UdayKumar change `\t\h` to `S` which will give you proper format

Comment: Thanks awesome !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("6  November 2017"));`

Comment: you changed the actual string . It's `6th of....` . so your code will not work. check here:- https://eval.in/895125

Comment: OP itself stated that  `$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('6th of November 2017'));` is not working

Comment: @Alive to Die yes but he is using `strtotime()` , to which he has provided invalid format which is `6th of November 2017` , it won't work. Hence i corrected above with proper format.

Comment: that's why he is asking a question that if format is not correct too, then how can he will go for correct solution. check other answer

Comment: Its upto him either he has to change function or he has to change format.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `6th of` to `6th` and it will be fine..

```
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('6th November 2017'));
echo ($newDate);
```

result

```
2017-11-06
```